# PHP curl via proxy

Tags: php, curl

My wordpress install (local development environment) is stuck behind a proxy and I'm having to hack plugins so they can see things likt the flickr API. I'm doing this by adding proxy options to curl requests.

Does anyone know of a way of setting curl options globally? There are no php.ini directives.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP CURL's directives are all done on a per-instance situation. Every new curl handle has to have the options set specifically each time, so, no... You'll have to hack the plugins, or compile a new libcurl/php with the options already set (at the risk of breaking everything else that uses curl).